# Hosted Python code coverage which is cost-free for FOSS projects?

Tags: python, github, unit-tests, qt, code-coverage

#### Context

I'm developing an application in Python with PyQt and for the testing I'm using the unittest Python module together with QtTest

The project is FOSS and is hosted on Github. I'm using TravisCI to build

#### Question

Now I'd like to add **code test coverage** for my project and am looking for something that:

- is hosted
- works with Python and Python's unittest module
- is cost-free (for FOSS projects)
- is integrated with Github

#### What I've found so far

The solutions I've been looking at (CodeClimate, CodeCov) requires the user to run a program locally on their own computer, and then upload the result to them

---

Grateful for help and with kind regards, Tord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that it's possible to combine [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) and [Codecov](https://codecov.io) and run [Coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io) on Travis CI using this stucture:

https://github.com/codecov/example-python/blob/master/.travis.yml

This assumes that your are using the Python `unittest` module, other examples (for pytest and nose) can be found here:

https://github.com/codecov/example-python

Hope this helps someone!

PS
In my case I am using unittest module but had to tweak the setup a bit, here is my complete configuration: https://pastebin.com/M1dKim4h